# Combine hex string with 0x

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-conversion

If first conversion is failed, then how to do another conversion?

I have a trigger that after data being insert to table, trigger will take the Hex data stored in the column, do conversion and update on another column (same row).

Currently the information from our client is, the programmer might send custom Hex data. Assuming the text is "hello" and the hex is HexData = "68656c6c6f". Currently on trigger, the conversion is like below:-

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), HexData, 2));
```

This will result in "hello". But if the programmer send the Hex as "0x68656c6c6f", this conversion will failed with error:-

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 9 Error converting data type varchar
>   to varbinary.

So if the programmer send as HexData = "0x68656c6c6f", this query works:-

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), [HexData], 1));
```

How do I put into this statement, if 2 is failed, than do 1?

**Programmer that send this information is from another department of my client. Though, they said programmer will send custom Hex. Either start with "0x" or direct Hex

## UPDATED:-

Trigger statement:-

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Hex_Automation] ON  [dbo].[DimHexRaw]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE [DimHexRaw] SET [Data_ASCII] = (CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), [HexData], 2))),
    [Timestamp_IO] = (dateadd(microsecond,[Macrosec],TRY_CONVERT([datetime2],[Timestamp]))),
    [DateKey] = (CONVERT([varchar](35),[Timestamp],(112))),
    [TimeKey] = (replace(CONVERT([varchar](8),[Timestamp],(108)),':',''))
    WHERE [DimHexRaw].[HexData] IS NOT NULL AND [DimHexRaw].[isProcess] = 0
END
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), '03141D365F531C558F0902FC65BF1851F58A21BE55ED8216AB3FD365F88C1FB347DAE176', 1)));
```

Return:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 13 Error converting data type varchar
>   to varbinary.

But with this script:-

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), 0x03141D365F531C558F0902FC65BF1851F58A21BE55ED8216AB3FD365F88C1FB347DAE176, 1));
```

it result in:-

> 6_SU üe¿QõŠ!¾Uí‚«?ÓeøŒ³GÚáv

How to combine '03141D365F531C558F0902FC65BF1851F58A21BE55ED8216AB3FD365F88C1FB347DAE176' with 0x so it can be 0x03141D365F531C558F0902FC65BF1851F58A21BE55ED8216AB3FD365F88C1FB347DAE176?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? SQL 2012 and later have `TRY_CONVERT`, `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_PARSE` which can be used to carry out safe conversion tests.

Comment: Ed, I have also using TRY_CONVERT, but the result, it pass and make the column become null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the performance, but `REPLACE` will have shorter syntax. Something like above:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), REPLACE([HexData], '0x', ''), 2)) AS ConvertedHex
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Your script works well with my trigger that using "INSERT SELECT *" on 4.5millions record in below 10mins and all hex converted as well..thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check if first two characters are **0x** and then do conversion.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT([HexData], 2) = '0x'
            THEN CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), [HexData], 1))
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), [HexData], 2))
       END
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Hi MH, can this syntax be use in trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) in SQL Server 2012+

```
DECLARE @Hexdata varchar(200) = '0x68656c6c6f'

IF TRY_CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 2) IS NOT NULL
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 2));
ELSE IF TRY_CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 1) IS NOT NULL
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 1));
ELSE
    SELECT 'No chance';

SET @Hexdata = '68656c6c6f';

IF TRY_CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 2) IS NOT NULL
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 2));
ELSE IF TRY_CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 1) IS NOT NULL
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), @Hexdata, 1));
ELSE
    SELECT 'No chance';
```